# MS-SQL inner join. more join criteria combined with OR - faster?

Tags: sql-server

I have an inner join, like this:

```
select 
  *  /*I define explicit columns*/ 
from
   sometable p
   innerjoin relatedtable t on
       t.sometablekey = p.sometablekey
       or t.sometablekey_2 = p.sometablekey--with this one, it runs a lot faster
where
   /*some where clauses, on both tables*/
```

without that "or condition" in the join, it runs a LOT slower (infact - so slow that I did not wait for the results).

currently neither t.sometablekey nor t.sometablekey_2 has any index on it (currently building those, no idea if it would help).

So - my question....how can it be, that the query runs a lot faster with the or? does the optimizer go crazy and pick some real bad query strategy?

I just cant get my head around it hehe ;)

Regards

Johannes Colmsee

P.S.: those indices are finished building now...and now...it runs about the same speed if i exclude the "or condition"...(infact the one without the or is a little bit faster now, as expected. The actual query I do - no row satisfies the "or condition" btw.)

P.P.S:

Question part2: those "sometablekey" and "sometablekey_2" were introduced by me, for a potential performance enhancement.
before the join was like this:

```
inner join relatedtable t on
 t.propa = p.propa
 and t.propb = p.propb
 and t.propc = p.propb
 or
 (
    t.propd_1 = p.propd
    or
    t.propd_2 = p.propd
 )
```

I was expecting a HUGE performance gain, but only got like 20%.
Could it be, that the new "real FK" relations aren't that fast cause we are using **varchar(40)** as **key**fields (which is kinda suboptimal, when you should use some numeric type or guid).

P.P.S: the query plan never mentioned any missing index btw, although - it IS benificial as commenters have said and my own observation proved. (have been building the indices when started this post)

Comment: With no indexes you have what are known as heaps. And the performance is going to be all over the place. It is possible that the OR causes a different plan based on data skew which allows the results to be returned faster. This should be a good example of why you want proper indexes on your tables.

Comment: This may be of use in properly indexing your tables  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345434.aspx